# Display hindi data store in nvarchar datatype without N prefix

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

SQL Server 2008 - Table contains nvarchar(max) datatype and store hindi & english data without N' prefix. like - "मांगलिक welcome" but in table store as "×æ¢»çÜ·¤  welcome".

Please guide how to display the data from SQL server in .net.

Answer (score 0):

The N prefix only denotes the string is NVARCHAR as opposed to VARCHAR

[See this for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025032/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-prefix-n-in-t-sql-statements)

C# is Unicode by default so your data will be ok.

In fact re-reading your question I'm not sure what you are asking.

Are you saying you store the data in the database WITHOUT the N prefix ? Is this done via .net ?

Can you please make your question clearer ?

** EDIT

I'm not sure you can. The data outside of the non Unicode code page will be lost.

[Check this page here for further details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721964/how-to-retrieve-unicode-data-stored-directly-in-non-unicode-field-as-varchar-for)

Comment: Question is how to display the data in .net from sql server in original format.

Comment: I just got the db where data store like i have mentioned... now i want to read the same and display using .net.

Answer (score 0):

First try to create a table as shown:

**`Create table TestLang (strText nvarchar(max))`**

Next try to insert values

```
insert into TestLang values ( N'मांगलिक')
insert into TestLang values ( N'Welcome')
```

Now try to search the name as shown:

**`SELECT * FROM TestLang WHERE strText LIKE N'मां%'`**

UPDATE:

If you want to display the data try this way:

```
string input = "0928;0940;0932;092E;";
Regex rx = new Regex(@"([0-9A-Fa-f]{4});");
string output = rx.Replace(input, match => ((char)Int32.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value, NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToString());
Output: "नीलम"
```

Took from **[here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/12a3558d-fe48-44fd-840e-03facfd9c944/unicode-to-hindi-devnagari-conversion-using-vbnet)**

Comment: In this way it working.. but table have already have data (×æ¢»çÜ·¤ welcome) without using N' prefix. Guide how to display the data.